# HowTo add another component on button click

Tags: svelte

I am creating a data entry table. I wish to add a new row to the table when the AddRow button is clicked.

My structure is a `<DataEntryForm>` component with a `<FormHeader>` subcomponent and one or more `<FormRow>` subcomponents.

Here's my first newbie attempt:

```
let numRows = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1];

<div class='efContainer'>
   <FormHeader />
   {#each numRows as num}
      <FormRow />
   {/each}
</div>

<Button on:click={() => numRows.push(1)}>Add Row</Button>
```

On initial run, 7 rows are created as specified by the length of the `numRows` array initial value.

However, clicking the `AddRow` button does nothing *(console logging shows that the array is being correctly updated. But of course nothing is telling the `#each` loop to re-run.)*

1. How should this app be restructured to make the AddRows button work?
2. The numRows array seems a klunky way to manage creating new rows. Is there a more Sveltic way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer to the Svelte tutorial on updating arrays and objects: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects

Since `numRows.push(1)` never updates the value of `numRows` Svelte won't detect the change. An easy fix is to replace `on:click={() => numRows.push(1)}` with `on:click={updateArray}` where `updateArray = () => {numRows = [...numRows, 1]}`

Comment: Ah, so that was it. I forgot about the need to destructure and re-assign. Actually, this inline code worked: `on:click={() => numRows = [...numRows, 1]}`  *Many thanks!*